# Is a portable Wok burner safe (indoors)

Tags: wok, safety

My Condo only has an electric stove, an no gas lines. I was looking to get a portable propane burner for a wok, so that I could effectively cook (I use it daily). Is this something that is safe to do inside? I've seen things like this use professionally, but as I do it personally and for family, I wanted to be sure the danger wasn't unreasonable for a non-professional chef

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10588/67

Comment: You can get dedicated wok induction hobs. I'm sure that would be safer.

Answer (score 3):

It can be safe - people use gas burning stoves inside on a regular basis.

The one thing you must do is ensure that there is adequate air-flow in your kitchen so as to prevent the build-up of carbon monoxide. This is as simple as leaving a window partially open when cooking.

Another concern would be how stable one of these is on your bench/work surface. Placing a large pan on top of a small foot-print stove will make it decidedly top heavy, so you should get one that is either low and flat (much like a regular cooking stove in a kitchen; e.g. [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N1RO9WG)) or one with feet that limit the movement/tipping capacity (e.g. [this one](https://www.msrgear.com/ie/products/stoves/whisperlite-universal/06632.html)). I have no affiliation with either product and make no claims about their ability to cook things, other than that MSR is a reliable outdoors brand. After all, you don't want your cooker to tip over and set your kitchen on fire or cause you to get burned from the hot food/pan and/or from the flame.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that a portable *propane* wok burner is safe for you to use inside.  Portable propane burners are ones similar to [this model](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/cooking-performance-group-wok13-lp-13-liquid-propane-wok-range-95-000-btu/351CPGWOKLP.html), or [one of these](https://www.stonefryingpans.com/top-5-wok-burners/).  They are high-powered burners that produce a lot of exhaust, and as such can only be used outside or with restaurant-grade ventilation.

However, portable *butane* wok burners, like [this one](https://cookingpotsnpans.com/kitchen-appliances/iwatani-35fw-portable-butane-stove-review/), are designed to be used indoors.  They require only an open window, or a regular consumer-grade stove hood, or honestly just a drafty apartment, as ventilation to use.  I have an Iwatani myself, that I use for wok-frying.

Comment: Most camping portable burners run on either methane (large tanks) or propane (canisters) in my experience - including the one linked in my answer. They will be suitable for small woks, though probably need the flat-bottomed ones rather than a full arc.

Comment: Yeah, but who wants to use a camp stove at home?  Stoves designed for the countertop are much more useful.

Comment: And ... most of the time when someone says "propane wok stove" they're referring to one of the high-power burners.  At least, in North America and Western Europe; it's possible that other kinds of propane stoves are more common elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a gas stove in my apartment but the BTUs it puts out cannot match a full on restaurant quality wok needed to get that signature 'Wok Hei' smoky flavour (Cantonese transliteration: 'Wok Breath')

I've used a propane torch as a cheap hack to get that authentic flavour alongside a carbon steel wok as described here:

https://www.seriouseats.com/2020/02/hei-now-youre-a-wok-star-a-fiery-hack-for-stir-frying-at-home.html

For minimal equipment required, this hack works surprising well